# fstream with unexpected output

Tags: c++, fstream

I need help figuring out why there are some extra symbols in the output file. There are 10 of them, always, no matter what is put in the original text file.
Thank you very much for your time!

```
"plain.txt"
```

> Mus velit, tincidunt vitae in enim id egestas eget.
>
> Nibh libero dignissim vitae elit. Quisque eleifend blandit pharetra
>   quisque.
>
> Ridiculus ac quam nisl suspendisse. Litora.
>
> Nostra torquent urna cursus fermentum nec magnis lobortis posuere
>   ultricies phasellus ultricies tellus mattis massa sagittis.
>
> Porta dolor aliquam iaculis.
>
> Litora. Maecenas nulla donec laoreet sit.
>
> Congue tempor habitasse, pulvinar purus erat proin ante hendrerit
>   hendrerit.
>
> Quam magna nibh sociosqu libero mi Laoreet pede vel.
>
> Suspendisse eu. Laoreet potenti enim, ad.
>
> Turpis augue viverra hendrerit praesent tristique velit.
>
> Dapibus ut a tortor vitae purus nisi.
>
> Pharetra molestie inceptos volutpat. Egestas bibendum ad ipsum diam.
>   Lorem.

```
"coded.txt"
```

> Qyw$zipmx0$xmrgmhyrx$zmxei$mr$irmq$mh$ikiwxew$ikix2
>   Rmfl$pmfivs$hmkrmwwmq$zmxei$ipmx2$Uymwuyi$ipimjirh$fperhmx$tlevixve$uymwuyi2
>   Vmhmgypyw$eg$uyeq$rmwp$wywtirhmwwi2$Pmxsve2
>   Tsvxe$hspsv$epmuyeq$megypmw2 Pmxsve2$Qeigirew$ryppe$hsrig$pesviix$wmx2
>   Gsrkyi$xiqtsv$lefmxewwi0$typzmrev$tyvyw$ivex$tvsmr$erxi$lirhvivmx$lirhvivmx2
>   Uyeq$qekre$rmfl$wsgmswuy$pmfivs$qm$Pesviix$tihi$zip2
>   Wywtirhmwwi$iy2$Pesviix$tsxirxm$irmq0$eh2
>   Xyvtmw$eykyi$zmzivve$lirhvivmx$tveiwirx$xvmwxmuyi$zipmx2
>   Hetmfyw$yx$e$xsvxsv$zmxei$tyvyw$rmwm2
>   Tlevixve$qspiwxmi$mrgitxsw$zspyxtex2$Ikiwxew$fmfirhyq$eh$mtwyq$hmeq2$Psviq2Qyw$zipmx0$xmrgmhyrx$zmxei$mr$irmq$mh$ikiwxew$ikix2
>   Rmfl$pmfivs$hmkrmwwmq$zmxei$ipmx2$Uymwuyi$ipimjirh$fperhmx$tlevixve$uymwuyi2
>   Vmhmgypyw$eg$uyeq$rmwp$wywtirhmwwi2$Pmxsve2
>   Tsvxe$hspsv$epmuyeq$megypmw2
>   Pmxsve2$Qeigirew$ryppe$hsrig$pesviix$wmx2
>   Gsrkyi$xiqtsv$lefmxewwi0$typzmrev$tyvyw$ivex$tvsmr$erxi$lirhvivmx$lirhvivmx2
>   Uyeq$qekre$rmfl$wsgmswuy$pmfivs$qm$Pesviix$tihi$zip2
>   Wywtirhmwwi$iy2$Pesviix$tsxirxm$irmq0$eh2
>   Xyvtmw$eykyi$zmzivve$lirhvivmx$tveiwirx$xvmwxmuyi$zipmx2
>   Hetmfyw$yx$e$xsvxsv$zmxei$tyvyw$rmwm2
>   Tlevixve$qspiwxmi$mrgitxsw$zspyxtex2$Ikiwxew$fmfirhyq$eh$mtwyq$hmeq2$Psviq2**ﾑﾑﾑﾑﾑﾑﾑﾑﾑﾑ** ***These symbols after number 2 are not supposed to be here.***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const char FILEIN[] = "plain.txt";
const char FILEOUT[] = "coded.txt";

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;


    inFile.open(FILEIN);
    outFile.open(FILEOUT);

    if (inFile.is_open() && outFile.is_open())
    {
        inFile.seekg (0, inFile.end);
        int size = inFile.tellg();
        inFile.seekg (0, inFile.beg);
        cout << size << endl;
        char * block = new char[size];

        inFile.read(block, size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            if (block[i] != '\n') block[i] += 4;
        outFile.write(block, size);

        cout << endl << "File encrypted" << endl;
        inFile.close(); outFile.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to access files" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could these mysterious symbols be originating in an EOF (end of file) marker in the input file `plain.txt`?  You can modify your code to check for this possibility.

Comment: Would `if (block[i] != '\n' && block[i] != EOF)` be sufficient to check for that marker? I tried that and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `ifstream::read` to read the contents of a file, it is necessary to open the file in binary mode. Similarly, when you use `ofstream::write` to write to a file, it is necessary to open the file in binary mode too.

```
inFile.open(FILEIN, std::ios::bin);
outFile.open(FILEOUT, std::ios::bin);
```

This is necessary to deal with the different ways various platforms deal with the newline character.

`size` returns a number that includes two characters for each newline. However, when the data is read, the two characters are read in only as one character. If you have a file with a single line, such as:

```
test
```

the value of `size` will be 6. When the data is ready, the fifth character will be `'\n'` and the sixth character will be junk. When that is written out, the output will have that junk.

Comment: How would you propose to fix this? Should I start counting for '\n' and subtract them from size? and I notice if I open the file in binary mode, the output will have no newline character.

Comment: Open the file in binary mode, using `std::ios::bin`. Don't change the values of `\n' and `\r`.

Comment: Wow this helps! but I'm not sure why and how. Open in binary mode and `if (block[i] != '\n' && block[i] != '\r')` Thank you Sahu. I understand the '\r' part was missing from the condition but why binary mode?!?! Sorry I just started learning c++ as you can tell.

Comment: @MizushimaHideyoshi, use a small file, like the I showed with only 4 visible characters and a newline. Read the file character by character and see what you get. Now use the method you are using and see how many characters you get. The crux of the matter is when a file is opened in text mode, the characters `'\n'` and `'\r'`, when they are in that sequence are translated as one character when the file is read. When the file is read in binary mode, those two characters are read as two characters.

Comment: I got 6 both methods. With binary mode & not excluding `'\r'` don't get new lines in the output, excluding it I get perfect output. Without binary mode I get the mysterious character even if I exclude the `'\r'`

Comment: That would be the result if you open the file in binary mode. If you open the file in text mode, you should see 5 using the first method and 6 using the second method.

Comment: I expected it to happen like that too based on what you said but it didn't. Maybe the problem isn't with `tellg()` but with `read()`

Comment: That is surprising to me. I don't know what else I can offer you.

Comment: Thank you, Rahu for helping me get it to work! and for trying to explain it to me. It gives me some food for thought at least. Thank you very much!